# Top Questions of the Week #1

Tags: discussion, status-completed, question-of-the-week, superuser-blog

We are planning on featuring every week the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://superuser.blogoverflow.com).  Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest).  If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each we week we are going to try to post about the question and it's contents.

Comment: you can also consider posting a digest of a number of interesting questions with commentary and followup -- see what Sam did here http://samsaffron.com/archive/2010/08/05/Interesting+answers+on+Stack+Overflow+from+July

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### [Blogged](http://superuser.blogoverflow.com/qotw/super-users-top-question-of-the-week-9-jan-16-jan)

[Fixing bent pins on a CPU](https://superuser.com/questions/229362/fixing-bent-pins-on-a-cpu)

> While replacing a mainboard in a desktop machine (see related question), I did something stupid. I inserted the CPU into the new mainboard, but didn't check for the right position. When it didn't immediately lock in, I pressed slightly before realizing what was wrong. The result was a number of bent pins.

Definitely one of the more Super User-ish questions that I've seen :-)

Answer (score 3):

[For what are the windows A:\ and B:\ drives used for?](https://superuser.com/questions/231273/for-what-are-the-windows-a-and-b-drives-used-for)

> In Windows you have a C:\ drive and everything beyond that is labeld with the following letter. So your second drive is D:\, your dvd is E:\ and if you put in a usb stick it becomes F:\ and the following drive G:\ and so on.
>
> But then, what and where are A:\ and B:\ ?

A good question that I myself didn't know the answer right away...

Comment: You must feel so young right now ;-P

Comment: Hey I remember using them.... as what I thought were Frisbee's when I was 4...

Comment: @IvoFlipse I feel old D: (And I'm not) =(

Comment: Awesome people never used A:\ and B:\, they used DF0: and DF1: =]

Comment: Some people blew PSU's while formatting DF0: and DF1: and DF2: and DF3: at the same time.