# Enable Non-Mods to edit meta questions with "protected" tags:

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

I was updating the [Top Question of the Week 1](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1869/top-question-of-the-week-1) question for the blog and wasn't able to make any changes due to the fact that some of the tags used were "protected".  Is there a way that we can enable users to make changes, but not the protected tags for cases like this?

Comment: Hmm, this [meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6248/cant-edit-a-post-thats-been-marked-with-a-moderator-tag-without-removing-the-ta) indicates `[status-complete]`

Comment: Well I've had several people this week who couldn't edit questions after I added the [featured] tag

Comment: @Ivo Does the featured tag even work on SU?

Comment: @Diago, I actually don't see it anywhere on the home page, so my guess would be no...

Comment: @Ivo. AFAIK it was only implemented on the StackExchange sites, not the original trilogy.

Comment: Then that needs fixing too

Comment: @Ivo Please no. I see no real need for it on any of the trilogy sites. It has a functional use on new sites, but not with the amount of hits we are taking already.

Comment: It's featuring Meta question with a max of 5, they are 'buried' in the sidebar. All I want is for the regular users to spot 'new' interesting/important meta questions @Diago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This has been fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72963/cannot-edit-a-post-after-a-mod-tag-was-added-to-it) and will be deployed soon.

Comment: Thank you @Jarrod!